# Clockwork for Laravel not working when ran through docker

Tags: laravel, docker, clockwork

I have previously used clockwork browser extension for debugging laravel queries. I have never had any issues getting the extension to work as expected. Recently I started using Laravel in a docker container. Now the Clockwork pane in Chrome dev tools is blank. None of the usual tabs i.e. Database etc and the requests pane on the left do not show at all. I would like give details about what I have tried so far but I literally have no idea where to start trying to fix the issue. In Clockwork settings there is a 'Code Path' field. Maybe this needs to be set to the path of the docker installation?? I can't find anything online or in the Clockwork documentation relating to this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Wow, I did not know about this package, it is like debugbar with steroids, super cool. But it is possible that it is not working as it asks you for `/real/path` and `/virtual/path` in the config, as you said, you should match it.

Comment: Yes it is possible but it is just a theory at the moment. Also, I am not sure what to use for the /real/path and /virtual/path when using docker?? nothing in the documentation about this. i have used clockwork extensively but never when using laravel with docker. now it is not working

Comment: For `virtual path` just use the path you get. If you have a volume, just use the second part, maybe you are using `/var/www/html` or similar, and for the real path, if you are on WSL or linux, just use that path to the root of Laravel